# Undervolt and underclock CPU to save energy

Tags: cpu, underclock, undervolting

I'm using old AMD Athlon 4400+ CPU on MB for mining. 
Since it's GPU extensive operation, main CPU is almost idle. 
I would like to undervolt and underclock it in order to save some extra power. 
I have MB DFi Lanparty UT witn NF4 so bios has plenty of settings.

Can you please navigate me, which settings I should change ?

Thank you!

Comment: If you are using windows, you can simply set the maximum CPU usage to say... 5% which will do the exact same, but its very safe to do. I've hooked up a wattage usage meter to my computer. At 100% it used 370 watts, setting it to 5% made it go down to 45 watts. I could still use the computer and the output did not change much. maybe went up to 50-60 watts. I obviously couldn't game well on it anymore, even though that used the video card and it was not capped, and yes the wattage spiked up with that which is logical. So if you are using windows, this is definitely the way to go.

Comment: I doubt there would be a noticeable effect if the cpu's already at idle, and undervolting or similar "overclocking" changes could cause errors. @LPChip Are there cpu frequency limits too? If the cpu changes frequencies, then keeping it lower has a similar effect, power used (& heat  produced) is lowered (at least on linux)

Comment: @Xen2050 Yes, instead, or in conjunction with the CPU's max % usage, you can also set a maximum CPU speed limit. Default its set to 0 hz which means: this setting is not in effect. To my knowledge, this setting the CPU speed is new since windows 10.